# raspberry pi2 RPIO PWM issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

Hi I am trying to use PWM from RPIO but I'm having some trouble.  The script I used was

```
from RPIO import PWM

servo = PWM.Servo()

# Add servo pulse for GPIO 17 with 1200µs (1.2ms)
servo.set_servo(17, 1200)

# Add servo pulse for GPIO 17 with 2000µs (2.0ms)
servo.set_servo(17, 2000)

# Clear servo on GPIO17
servo.stop_servo(17)
```

The code executes fine using:

```
sudo python3 servoEx.py
```

in terminal.  The output is:

```
Using hardware: PWM
PW increments:  10us
Initializing channel 0...
add_channel_pulse: channel=0, gpio=17, start=0, width=120
init_gpio 17
add_channel_pulse: channel=0, gpio=17, start=0, width=200
clear_channel_gpio: channel=0, gpio=17
shutting down dma channel 0
clear_channel: channel=0
```

but with the servo connected to gpio 17, nothing happens, I even tried hooking it up to an LED to see if I get some output but I dont.  Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: There are two different pin out numberings in use on the Pi, BCM and BOARD, are you sure you've got the right pin?

Comment: Yea I've looked into that too.  I just ended up using RPi instead but it has a lot of jitter or the servo motors so I would like to switch back to RPIO if I can get this issue fixed